# PCRE Pattern match to website URL

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm trying to configure a website plugin and need to set a PCRE url pattern for certain pages on my site.
 I need to exclude pages which are in the following patterns:

http://www.autonews.com/automarket_news/news/1800699/

http://www.kolesa.com/news/sometexthere/

Would anyone know how to do this using PCRE expressions..?

Answer (score 0):

Writing a correct `regex` that can match any valid URL is not an easy job. Fortunately, there is no need to write such a `regex`, `PHP` provides better tools.

Use function [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to split the `URL` to components then use simple comparisons, lookups (or even simple `regex`es if you really need them) to analyze the URL pieces and decide what to do next.

Sample code:

```
$url = 'http://www.autonews.com/automarket_news/news/1800699/etc';
$pieces = parse_url($url);

if ($pieces['host'] == 'www.autonews.com' &&
    strpos($pieces['path'], '/automarket_news/news/1800699/') === 0) {
    // matches, do something
} else {
    // doesn't match, do something else
}
```